# Why specify route parameter type in web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api end point with a route parameter. It works with or without the route parameter type. I just would like to know why specify this in the following code?

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{myId:int}")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetData([FromUri] int myId)
{
    //code here
}
```

This snippet `[Route("{myId:int}")]`. Why specify the int? There is already a int in this `[FromUri] int myId`. Wouldn't int for the route be redundant? Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Please see this example:

```
[Route("users/{id:int}"]
public User GetUserById(int id) { ... }

[Route("users/{name}"]
public User GetUserByName(string name) { ... }
```

Here, the first route will only be selected if the "id" segment of the URI is an integer. Otherwise, the second route will be chosen.

---

So in your case it's not required. But would be necessary if you need smarter route resolution. There are many different constraints that you can use. For example `{x:minlength(10)}` - string with min length of 10. `{x:max(10)}` - Matches an integer with a maximum value of 10. `{x:regex(^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$)}` - regex constraints etc.

You can find all the available constraints in the [documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints).

Comment: Actually, not quite. You need to specify the `Order` property (`[Route("users/{id:int}", Order = 0)]` and `[Route("users/{name}", Order = 1)]`). .NET Reflection doesn't guarantee an order when reading attributes, so they could be entered in the wrong order into the route table (randomly, and possibly different upon different compilations). In this case, the route with the constraint needs to be executed first.

Comment: Wow. I learned something new today. This is very elegant. Now Im gonna go back and change some of my end points to comply with this.